# Impact of variable change on the solution of $x^3+y^3=z$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, soft-question

Let $x,y,z$ be coprime integers such that $$x^3+y^3=z$$ I am trying to to gain some insights into the impact of variable substitution on the solution set of the original equation.

Here is what I mean:

Let the solution set $(x,y,z)$ exist. There are integers a,b,c such that
$$ ax+ by+ cz=0$$ with $abc\neq 0$

If I substitute for instance $x$ in the first equation, I will obtain:
$$-(by+cz)^3+(ay)^3=az$$

My question is: Is this equation equivalent to $x^3+y^3=z$. In other words, do they have the same solution set when $x,y,z$ run over the complex numbers?

Comment: By definition, yes. But you just added two more variables into this diophantine equation which make it harder, not simpler.

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.- You have an elliptic curve of difficult solution.

Consider Selmer's equation $x^3+y^3=Az^3....(*)$ where $A$ is a cube-free integer. It has been established that if $aX^3+bY^3+cZ^3=0$ where $abc=A$ has a solution then a solution of $(*)$ is given by
$$x=u^3+3u^2v-6uv^2+v^3\\y=-u^3+6u^2v-3uv^2-v^3\\Az^3=9uv(u-v)3((u^2-uv+v^2)^3$$ which is satisfied taking
$$u=aX^3\\v=-bY^3\\u-v=-cZ^3 (\text{so }z=3XYZ(u^2-uv+v^2))$$ In your case you must have to take your $z$ in the form $Az^3$ (*you know your $z$ cannot be a cube)* if you want to apply this. I repeat your equation is difficult, very difficult really.